# Why do we need to install a variable frequency drive to reduce the energy consumption of a motor?

Tags: power, frequency, induction-motor, electromagnetic

I have read that the power consumed by a motor under various load conditions is not constant according to the answers to this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149296/is-power-consumed-by-a-motor-under-various-load-conditions-constant).

The electrical energy input changes according to the torque required to rotate the load by changing the amount of current drawn from the supply source.

Why do we need to install a variable frequency drive to reduce the energy consumption of a motor? Is it a second way to reduce the energy consumption of a motor?

Comment: Why provide more power than needed?

Comment: You don't need to. There are other ways of reducing energy consumption. But a VFD is sometimes the easiest and most flexible way.

Comment: If you need a constant motor speed, a 3 phase motor may do if you got a 3 phase connection to the power grid.

Answer (score 2):

The power consumed by a motor is the electrical equivalent of the mechanical power required to drive the load plus losses in the motor. There are ways to manufacture motors to make them more efficient, but but little or nothing can be done to improve the efficiency of a motor once it has been manufactured.

Variable frequency drives (VFDs) can only reduce (or sometimes increase) the operating speed. Reducing operating speed reduces the energy used, but it also reduces the work done by the driven load machine. In some situations, as mentioned to my answer to your other question, that results in accomplishing the task by using less energy.

There are no ways to reduce the energy consumption of a motor. There are several ways of reducing the speed at which a machine operates. A VFD is a very efficient method and offers some other operational advantages.

Comment: Dear Charles Cowie,

Thank you very much for your answer, I am grateful to you to spend your time answering my question.

Just what I would like to understand how does reducing the operating speed reduces the energy used? I mean what happens inside the motor to make it consumes less power? or does reducing the operating speed reduce the mechanical power required to drive the load, which is then reflected in reducing the electrical supply?

Comment: Reducing the operating speed, with few exceptions, reduces the mechanical power required to drive the load. That power reduction is reflected in reducing the electrical supply power.